# Changeable REST API host address for Android or Ionic App.

Tags: android, ionic-framework, web, ionic2, hosting

I am about to finish my Android App developed by Ionic Framework , I hosted my Rest API spring boot application in Heroku free tier.
Now all the API services is available in https://myapp.herokuapp.com (not actual).

So all the API calls from android App is going to

Host= "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/"

ServiceName= "getservice"

rest.get(Host+ServiceName)

It's working fine , i have not uploaded the app in playstore yet.

My Concern is if 1 month later Heroku stops it's free service and i have to move my spring application to somewhere else, the host name will be change.
And if 100 users already downloaded my App then it will stop work till they go for a update.

If they don't want to take update app won't work.

Is there any other way where this host name can be changed or by some other means where i wont depend on a particular API host name ??

Please Help

Comment: Buy own domain and set ALIAS record to point some other address.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Use [Ionic Pro's Live Deploy](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/) to push such changes. In free Starter account you get [100 Live Deploys](https://ionicframework.com/pro/pricing) so one of them might be changing that URL if needed. I must admit I haven't yet used that feature but it sounds very useful.
2. As @Selvin suggested you might want to get your own domain so that you can use DNS settings to route the traffic to desired server (e.g. using domain provider settings like ALIAS or by using Amazon Route 53 which gives you more options). [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) explain how to configure this.

These options are not exclusive and give you more flexibility in managing your service and your app in the future.